# MongoDB updating array of objects does not work as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Got multiple documents in a db one of which looks like this:

```
{
   "searchWord":[
      "pizz",
      "pizza"
   ],
   "result":[
      {
         "idMeal":1,
         "strMeal":"test1",
         "strInstructions":"test1"
      },
      {
         "idMeal":2,
         "strMeal":"test2",
         "strInstructions":"test2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Tried to solve it like this:

eg:

```
 db.meals.updateOne(
    {
      "searchWord": "pizz",
      "result": { $elemMatch: { idMeal: "1"  } }
    },
    { $set: { 'result.$.strMeal' : "UPDATED" } }
 )
```

This doesnt update the respective subdocument only the 2nd as if I wrote

> { $set: { 'result.1.strMeal' : "UPDATED" } }

*(Which will result in the 2nd subdocument being updated)*

This is the other idea (Same result)

```
db.meals.updateOne(
  { searchWord: "pizz", 'result.idMeal': 319012 },
  { $set: { "result.$.strMeal" : "fsdf" } }
)
```

What I dont seem to understand is its exactly the syntax that is provided by mongo yet it doesnt work

**The "$" operator doesnt pick up which array of objects I wanna update**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----) in your `$set` for multiple positional element

```
db.collection.update({
  "searchWord": "pizz"
},
{
  $set: {
    "result.$[r].strMeal": "UPDATED"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "r.idMeal": 1
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2NVNmywsdc) for your reference.